# How to logging when i use SSM Automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am trying to use `SSM Automation` so I made a document by myself and tried to run it.

**My Problem:**

I tried logging in `AWS Docs` [Logging Automation action output with CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-logging.html), but logging is not working.

I tried the way it works in the console, but it doesn't work, what's the reason?

SSM Automation works fine, but why is there no logging?

**My proposed solution:**

- I set it up the same as [Logging Automation action output with CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-logging.html)
- This is what i set it.

[image]